# SQL Conditional selection - Can I use Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query with multiple joins. Based on a value I need to set the value of one of the select values to 'N/A' if it's not it should be queried from the table. Can I use Case from this, pls let me know.

Assume the below query:

```
select distinct name,id,branch,Related 
from table1;
```

And the requirement is

Need to set the "**Related**" to "**N/A**" if branch is not "computer science" else it should get the value from table1.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `case` expression for this.

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN BRANCH = 'computer science' THEN RELATED ELSE 'N/A' END AS RELATED` will work, assuming `RELATED` is a character type.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `case..when` structure as :

```
select distinct name,id,branch,
       ( case when Related = 'computer science' then
           related
         else
          'N/A'
         end
        ) as related
  from table1
```